# Why does this select menu fail in new version combo of jQuery and JQM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Would like to extend this code but noticed it fails to limit the selection (by count) in the newer versions of jQuery and JQM.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59ng8wdn/) that shows it works with jQuery 1.8.3 and JQM 1.2.0.

The jQuery (less the Select itself) code is here:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    $("#select").on("change", function () {
        var selected = $("option:selected", this).length;
        if (selected == 4) {
            $("option:not(:selected)", this).prop("disabled", true);
            $(this).selectmenu("refresh");
        }
        if (selected < 4) {
            $("option:disabled", this).prop("disabled", false);
            $(this).selectmenu("refresh");
        }
         arr = new Array();
                    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(index, item) {
                        arr.push($(item).val());
                        console.log(arr);
                    });
    });
});
```

You can simulate the failure in the fiddle by switching to jQuery 1.11.0 and JQM 1.4.4.

Then, select a 5th option which should be prevented but is allowed.

What am I missing that would cause this to fail with the new versions?

PS: Any pointers to the best approach to populate the select box with an $.ajax GET are appreciated too since that will be my next step. I'm using a POST to save the selection but want to present the user with what they've already saved when they need to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `true` as a second argument to the `selectmenu` function, to force it to refresh the menu after disabling the option. [Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59ng8wdn/5/)

```
$(this).selectmenu("refresh", true);
```

Comment: Yes, that does the trick! I suspect that requirement may be buried somewhere in release notes between the various versions. Thanks!